# What is the influence of multicolinearity on the likelihood ratio test?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multicollinearity, likelihood-ratio

I learned the two concepts separately and I try to find out how these concepts relate to each other.

To illustrate the question introduce three models. The models establish a relation between age (AGE) and income (INC). LNINC is the logged version of INC. The goal is to find out whether we should include INC or LNINC in our model.

> 1.2: PRICE = C + b2*AGE+ b3*INC   with Log likelihood: -2462.164

> 1.3: PRICE = C + b2*AGE+ b3*LNINC with Log likelihood: -2440.609

> 1.4: PRICE = C + b2*AGE+ b3*INC + b4*LNINC with Log likelihood: -2439.389

We see that model 1.2 and 1.3 are nested in 1.4, so we can test 1.2 vs 1.4 and 1.3 vs 1.4.

**1.2 vs 1.4**

$$H0: b_4 = 0$$
$$H1: b_4 \neq 0$$

**1.3 vs 1.4**

$$H0: b_3 = 0$$
$$H1: b_3 \neq 0$$

The following test is used: $L R=2\left(\log L_{1.4}-\log L_{1.2}\right)$ for the first situation. The same principle applies for the second test.

So far so good, I recently learned about multicollinearity and that appears when two parameters are strongly correlated. The implication of multicollinearity is that the standard error of the test gets large and it is hard to conclude significance of your coefficients.

In model 1.4 I'd argue that INC and LNINC are strongly correlated because, although one parameter is transformed, it still contains the same information. Consequently, I'd expect that multicollinearity plays a role here. Although, we are checking the significance of coefficients, we do it here on the basis of likelihood and not on the basis of standard error, so that can be an argument why multicollinearity does not play a role.

**Questions**

- What is the relation between multicollnearity and likelihood?
- What is the effect of multicollinearity on the Likelihood ratio test?
- How to check for the influence of multicolinearity in testing 1.2-3 vs 1.4? Is there a quantity like Variance Inflation Factor in the context of likelihood?

Comment: Which likelihood are you using?

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your quick reply. I used the Log likelihood under the maximum likelihood criterium and the LR test statistic as used in the example. Due to my limited knowlegde I am not aware of other likelihoods. Does this answer the question?

Comment: LNINC looks better in your results than INC so if you choose one then you might choose LNINC for that reason alone.  Can you justify using both from a theoretical point of view? It would certainly complicate any attempt to explain your results as well as increasing uncertainty in the individual coefficients

Comment: @Henry I see, it would not make sense to keep both in it. But the "large" model with INC and LNINC is used to test the restricted models 1.2 and 1.3 against. However, due to strong expected correlation between these variables I would like to understand how the multicollinearity problem relates to the regression of the unrestricted model 1.4 and what implications that has on subsequent LR-testing, if there is any implication ofcourse